# Time Lock Bukkit plugin stuck at eternal day

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I've set my Minecraft world to eternal day and I want to make it back to normal day and night cycles. How do I do this? The `/tl` command does not work!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about the [Time Lock Bukkit plugin](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/timelock/), the command you need to use to reset the time to normal is

```
/tl normal
```